# What is the difference between pycrypto and crypto packages in python?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, pycrypto

I am new to encryption and hashing in python. I need this for authentication in one of my flask project. So my friend told me to use crypto package but when i searched it up i got [crypto](https://pypi.org/project/crypto/) and [pycrypto](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/) packages in the result. The thing is I know both of them are for encryption utility but I am confused as to which one to use. Is one of them better than the other or is one of them just a wrapper of the other?

Or

is there another better encryption package for python that I should use instead of the two mentioned above?
I hope someone who have used these packages could help me. Thanks.

Comment: Just looking at the usage documentation in your links, pycrypto appears to be a library and crypto appears to be a CLI utility.

Comment: pardon me if the question is trivial but then why does it have a [pypi.org page dedicated for the crypto package](https://pypi.org/project/crypto/).

Comment: Nothing stops pypi from hosting CLI programs. For CLI programs written in Python, it makes for an easy way to distribute. awscli is another example of a CLI program on pypi (and one of the most downloaded on the site)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two packages serve very different goals: `crypto` is a command line utility, which is intended to encrypt files, while `pycrypto` is a Python library which can be used from within Python to perform a number of different cryptographic operations (hashing, encryption/decryption, etc). `pycrypto` would be the more appropriate choice for implementing authentication within Python.

I will note that Python also includes [some cryptographic primitives in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypto.html), which may be more suitable for your use case.

Edit: As has been noted in the comments, `pycrypto` is no longer maintained, and a library such as [`cryptography`](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/) or [`pycryptodome`](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/) should be used instead.

Comment: pardon me if the question is trivial but then why does it have a [pypi.org page dedicated for the crypto package](https://pypi.org/project/crypto/). Ithought pypi.org hosted packages for python and not CLI utilities.

Comment: @SarathSajan Not a trivial question at all :) jordanm's comment on your original post has responded to this, but I'll also point you towards [the setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html#console-scripts) which shows how this is implemented. Being able to install command line tools with pip (& therefore with setuptools) is expected behaviour.

Comment: Concerning _pycrypto_, it should be added that this library is legacy ([here](https://theartofmachinery.com/2017/02/02/dont_use_pycrypto.html)), no longer maintained and should not be used. The successor is [_pycryptodome_](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/).

Comment: @Topaco Cheers, I've noted that in the answer.

Comment: It all seems very confusing in Python, there is Crypto, pycrypto, pycryptodome, rsa, and OpenSSL libraries. It would be far nicer if there was one definitive way rather than this confusing array of seemingly overlapping options. I'd be happy to hear the opinions of someone who could answer that.